# Add text contents to Photoshop layer via the comtypes library

Tags: python-3.x, photoshop, win32com

I want to add a text layer to a psd file. I was able to add a layer but I don't know how to write a content or to locate the content in that layer.
Can anyone tell me?

I imported win32com and this is what I got for now.

```py
import win32com.client

psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")

psApp.Open('file path')         # Opens a PSD file
doc = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument  # Get active document object

layers = doc.ArtLayers
newTextLayer = layers.add # add a layer
newTextLayer.kind = 2 # specify a text layer

newTextLayer.name = 'new' # name the layer

newTextLayer = 'text content' # this line is what I am struggling with.


doc.save
doc.close
```

---

**Edit:** I am using python 3.6. and Photoshop CC.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to format your code using Markdown (or the internal editor) so that's more clear for other readers to help you. See [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow) .

The `newTextLayer` is basically inheriting from the main `TextItem` object. That's why to solve your problem you need to do this:

```py
import win32com.client

psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")

psApp.Open('file path') # Opens a PSD file
doc = psApp.Application.ActiveDocument # Get active document object

layers = doc.ArtLayers
newTextLayer = layers.add # add a layer

newTextLayer.kind = 2 # specify a text layer
newTextLayer.name = 'new' # name the layer

newTextLayer.TextItem.Contents = 'text content'
doc.save
doc.close
```